# jQuery - Pre-select from dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function to select menu options but even though the item is selected when the dropdown is clicked, it isn't pre-selected on load. In other words the `.selected` is not receiving the name of the active `li`.

```js
var selected = $(".selected");
var dropdown = $(".dropdown-list");
var optionList = $(".dropdown-list li");

function menuClick() {
  selected.click(function() {
    dropdown.toggleClass("active");

    if (dropdown.hasClass("active")) {
      optionList.click(function() {
        if (optionList.hasClass("active")) {
          $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
        } else {
          $(this).addClass("active");
        }
        dropdown.removeClass("active");
        selected.children("span").html($(this).html());
      });
    }
  });
}
menuClick();
```

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:300,400,500,700";
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  width: 90px;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown .selected {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  padding: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.dropdown .selected i {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.5rem;
}

.dropdown .selected:hover {
  /*box-shadow: 0 4px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) !important;*/
}

.dropdown .dropdown-list {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 1px 4px 7px 0px #00000012 !important;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
  transform: translateY(0%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.67, 0, 1);
  transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.67, 0, 1);
}

.dropdown .dropdown-list li {
  padding: 1rem;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease;
  transition: all 200ms ease;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-list li.active {
  background: rgba(63, 81, 181, 0.1);
}

.dropdown .dropdown-list li:not(.active):hover {
  background: rgba(63, 81, 181, 0.02);
}

.dropdown .dropdown-list.active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
  transform: translateY(0%);
  max-height: 260px;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="dropdown">
  <p class="selected"><span>Refine</span> <i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_down</i></p>
  <ul class="dropdown-list">
    <li class="active">All Time</li>
    <li>Recent</li>
    <li>Today</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You need a way to save the selected item, either in your server or in browser storage. Also, what was the reason to use a list instead of [dropdown](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a simple filter on the active element to get it's text into the span on page load

Something like:

```
selected.find('span').text(function(){
    return optionList.filter('.active').text()
})
```

```js
var selected = $(".selected");
var dropdown = $(".dropdown-list");
var optionList = $(".dropdown-list li");

// set the selected text on page load based on current active item
selected.find('span').text(function(){
    return optionList.filter('.active').text()
})

function menuClick() {
  selected.click(function() {
    dropdown.toggleClass("active");

    if (dropdown.hasClass("active")) {
      optionList.click(function() {
        if (optionList.hasClass("active")) {
          $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
        } else {
          $(this).addClass("active");
        }
        dropdown.removeClass("active");
        selected.children("span").html($(this).html());
      });
    }
  });
}


menuClick();
```

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:300,400,500,700";
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  width: 90px;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown .selected {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  padding: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.dropdown .selected i {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.5rem;
}

.dropdown .selected:hover {
  /*box-shadow: 0 4px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) !important;*/
}

.dropdown .dropdown-list {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 1px 4px 7px 0px #00000012 !important;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
  transform: translateY(0%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.67, 0, 1);
  transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.67, 0, 1);
}

.dropdown .dropdown-list li {
  padding: 1rem;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease;
  transition: all 200ms ease;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-list li.active {
  background: rgba(63, 81, 181, 0.1);
}

.dropdown .dropdown-list li:not(.active):hover {
  background: rgba(63, 81, 181, 0.02);
}

.dropdown .dropdown-list.active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
  transform: translateY(0%);
  max-height: 260px;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="dropdown">
  <p class="selected"><span>Refine</span> <i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_down</i></p>
  <ul class="dropdown-list">
    <li class="active">All Time</li>
    <li>Recent</li>
    <li>Today</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```